# Microsoft BOT framework webchat JS not working in IE

Tags: botframework

We are using below latest/webchat.js in our UI app-

This is working in chrome & edge, but NOT working in IE. this is production issue.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using? Could you share more information about how you are integrating the Bot Framework webchat, your post is very limited currently...

Comment: Additional to what @mick mentioned, IE11 is the only supported version of webchat (v4).